# How to Put OR condition in Xpath using Html AGility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a question about HTML Agility PAck

I want to get the node collection whose Div's isPublished property is either "False" or "false".

How can I add the OR condition in XPATH.
Below is my code, which does not work. It returns null.

```
 HtmlNodeCollection numbers = 
 htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@ispublished='false|False']");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@ispublished='false' or @ispublished='False']");
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@ispublished='false' or @ispublished='False']");
```

More on [xpath or](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-OrExpr)